# Is there way to limit number of active instance of particular orchestration?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Is there way to limit number of active instance of particular orchestration ?

Comment: Yes, but exactly how depends on what you're trying to do and why you think you need to.

Comment: Also, which version of BizTalk are you using?  You have tagged it with 3 different versions

Comment: See this blog about one way of throttling the number of instances of an Orchestration.  https://connectedpawns.wordpress.com/2016/05/21/blast-from-the-past-biztalk-orchestration-throttling-pattern/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can, but it depends on your requirements. You need to have the separate host instance for that. Create it and bind it with your orchestration. Also there are some settings you need to do. I have no idea about what you want exactly. But throttling would be your solution.
[Read more about throttling settings from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559893.aspx)

[image]